# How can I customize filtering in DJango Admin?

Tags: django

`admin.py`

```py
class authUserMenu(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "user_id", "menu_id","is_active"]

    class Meta:
        Model = AuthUserMenu
admin.site.register(AuthUserMenu, authUserMenu)
```

`models.py`

```py
class AuthUserMenu(models.Model):   # USER VS MENU relation
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True, null=True)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_menu'
        ordering     = ['user','menu','is_active']

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.id
        return str([self.user.username,'>>>>>>', self.menu.menu_name])
```

In my Django admin panel
[image]

- When filtering with username should only show some menus under some condition... How can I achieve this?
- Suppose here for the username 4 menu is showing. But it should show 2 menu. This may obtain by db querying.
- 
- This is how A user related to menus

[image]

Comment: What is the condition for filtering the available Menus? Can you show the models and explain how a User relates to Menu choices

Comment: Bro. I have added an image of the relation.. Can you please check it if it is understandable

Comment: what I wrote is for views.py. I think lain can solve this..

Answer (score 1):

You need some JS to call a view asyncronously every time the `user` field is updated and change the options in the `menu` field with the response. The package [`django-autocomplete-light`](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) is a popular choice for exactly this, especially [updating field values from other fields](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form) is relevant

forms.py

```
class AuthUserMenuForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AuthUserMenu
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'menu': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                url='menu-autocomplete',
                forward=['user']
            )
        }
```

views.py

```
class MenuAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Menu.objects.all()
        user = self.forwarded.get('user', None)
        if user:
            # Not clear exactly what your filter would be here so left it but you have user available
            qs = qs.filter(...)
        return qs
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('menu-autocomplete/', views.MenuAutocomplete.as_view(), name='menu-autocomplete'),
    ...
]
```

```
class AuthUserMenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AuthUserMenuForm
    list_display = ["__str__", "user_id", "menu_id", "is_active"]

admin.site.register(AuthUserMenu, AuthUserMenuAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, bro your help... I am trying to solve it using your solution.

Comment: Please Mark it as correct. An an upvote if Worked

Answer (score 0):

Sorry But the filter's you are applying for admin is only valid for how they are Going to look on the admin panel it won't customize your model properties and in order to achieve that you need to create a filter as eg ...

```
user = self.get_object()
articles = Article.objects.filter(author_id)
```

Something like that

Comment: Where can I put this code? can you please explain it more?

Comment: This I was defining for views.py